# Copy variable ranges from one sheets columns to another sheets rows

Tags: vba, excel, variables, copy

I am stucked at copying variable ranges from one worksheet to another. I have a workbook with one sheet that name is test. It contains Data in columns a to e with the fact, that in column a are stored the names of the projects, in b are stores account numbers in c description and in e are the values for account numbers.
The point is, that in column A I have the name of the project and then is the column filled with empty cells, in column B are the account numbers and summation. When next Project begins, it is showed new project name in column a.... and so on total approx 2.000 entries in total, divided into 50 projects. I need to copy just data for one project into another sheet (columns b and e), starting at position A1, next project on c1 and so on.
Can anyone help? with vba code for it?
Too many variables for me..:-)

```
Sub CopyCells1()
Dim lRow, x As Integer, y As Integer, z As Integer

lRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).row
x = 0
z = 1
Do
x = x + 1
If ActiveSheet.Range("A" & x) <> "" Then
        y = x + 1
        If ActiveSheet.Range("A" & y) <> "" Then
        Range(("b" & x), ("b" & y)).Copy
        Sheets("test2").Range(z & 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Else: y = y + 1
    End If
Else: x = x + 1
End If
Loop Until x = lRow
z = z + 2
End Sub
```

Another code I tried without success...

```
Sub CopyCells2()
Dim lRow, x As Integer, y As Integer, z As Integer

lRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For x = 1 To lRow Step 1
y = x + 1
z = 1
If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsText(Range("A" & x)) Or Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Range("A" & x)) Then

        If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsText(Range("A" & y)) Or Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Range("A" & y)) Then
        Range(("b" & x), ("b" & y)).Copy
        Sheets("test2").Range(1 & z).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Else: y = y + 1
    End If

End If
z = z + 2
Next x

End Sub
```

---

Solved.
OK, so here´s the code, that works as it should, if anyone need it...;-)
Thanx to Koen from mrexcel.com

```
Sub CopyData()

Set DataSht = Worksheets("test")
Set ResSht = Worksheets("results")

startrw = 1
endrw = DataSht.Range("B" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
rescol = 1

For Rw = startrw To endrw
copy_data = False
If DataSht.Range("A" & Rw).Value <> "" Then
    'New project start
    proj_start_rw = Rw
ElseIf Rw = endrw Then
    'Last row of data, copy last block
    proj_end_rw = Rw
    copy_data = True
ElseIf DataSht.Range("A" & Rw + 1).Value <> "" Then
    'Next row filled, this one empty, copy whole block to the result sheet
    proj_end_rw = Rw
    copy_data = True
Else
    'Empty row, do nothing
End If
If copy_data = True Then
    DataSht.Range("B" & proj_start_rw & ":B" & proj_end_rw).Copy Destination:=ResSht.Cells(1, rescol)
    DataSht.Range("E" & proj_start_rw & ":E" & proj_end_rw).Copy Destination:=ResSht.Cells(1, rescol + 1)
    rescol = rescol + 2
End If
Next Rw

End Sub
```

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: Honestly, I have no clue how it can be done...

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! As you may have skipped the intro for this site: “Code this for me” questions are generally frowned upon around here, however, we’d love to help you learn! If you could, please post any code you have already tried. For further information on posting a question, you might want to have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi @Dave, I see you've posted the code which I've assumed you've tested; where are you now running into issues?

Comment: Well, it gives me ridiculous numbers as variants x, y and z and doesn´t copy anything..:-( Updated version doesn´t work at al...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example how I did something similar.  I hope it helps

```
For Each rng In rng2.Cells


If rng.Offset(-1) <> rng Then


        cl = cl + 2
        rw = 1
        sht.Cells(rw, cl) = rng.offset(0,1)
        sht.Cells(rw, cl) = rng.Offset(0, 4)


    Else
        rw = rw + 1
        sht.Cells(rw, cl) = rng.offset(0,1)
        sht.Cells(rw, cl) = rng.Offset(0, 4)


End If
Next
```

rng2 would be your range of projects.